# Reactor - how to retry on hot flux without dropping elements?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

I have an infinite hot flux of data. I am about to engage in carrying out an operation on each element in the stream, each of which returns a Mono which will complete (one way or another) after some finite time.

There is the possibility of an error being thrown from these operations. If so, I want to resubscribe to the hot flux without missing anything, retrying elements that were in the middle of being processed when the error was thrown (i.e. anything that did not complete successfully).

What do I do here? I can tolerate repeated operations on the same elements, but not losing elements entirely from the stream.

I've attempted to use a ReplayProcessor to handle this, but I can't see a way of making it work without repeating a lot of operations that might well have succeeded (using a very conservative timeout), or losing elements due to new elements overriding old ones in the buffer (as below).

Test case:

```
    @Test
    public void fluxTest() {


        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("one");
        strings.add("two");
        strings.add("three");
        strings.add("four");

        ConnectableFlux<String> flux = Flux.fromIterable(strings).publish();

        //Goes boom after three uses of its method, otherwise 
        //returns a mono. completing after a little time
        DangerousClass dangerousClass = new DangerousClass(3);

        ReplayProcessor<String> replay = ReplayProcessor.create(3);

        flux.subscribe(replay);

        replay.flatMap(dangerousClass::doThis)
              .retry(1)
              .doOnNext(s -> LOG.info("Completed {}", s))
              .subscribe();

        flux.connect();

        flux.blockLast();
    }


    public class DangerousClass {

        Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DangerousClass.class);

        private int boomCount;
        private AtomicInteger count;

        public DangerousClass(int boomCount) {
            this.boomCount = boomCount;
            this.count = new AtomicInteger(0);
        }

        public Mono<String> doThis(String s) {
            return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
                LOG.info("doing dangerous {}", s);
                if (count.getAndIncrement() == boomCount) {
                    LOG.error("Throwing exception from {}", s);
                    throw new RuntimeException("Boom!");
                }
                return s;
            }).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(600));
        }
    }
```

This prints:

```
doing dangerous one
doing dangerous two
doing dangerous three
doing dangerous four
Throwing exception from four
doing dangerous two
doing dangerous three
doing dangerous four
Completed four
Completed two
Completed three
```

One is never completed.

Comment: I've come up with a heavy-handed solution that uses a WorkQueueProcessor instead of a replay processor, and a SynchronizedCollection - before doing the dangerous task, each element is added to the collection. Downstream from the flatmap, each element is removed now that success has been assured.

On an error, elements are moved from the collection to the processor for retry. 

This seems both clunky and blocking, and I'd hoped there was some more 'reactive' way of approaching the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error (at least in the above example) can only occur in the `flatMap(dangerousClass::doThis)` call - so resubscribing to the root `Flux` and replaying elements when this one `flatMap()` call has failed seems a bit odd, and (probably) isn't what you want to do.

Instead, I'd recommend ditching the `ReplayProcessor` and just calling retry on the inner `flatMap()` call instead, so you end up with something like:

```
ConnectableFlux<String> flux = Flux.range(1, 10).map(n -> "Entry " + n).publish();

DangerousClass dangerousClass = new DangerousClass(3);

flux.flatMap(x -> dangerousClass.doThis(x).retry(1))
        .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("Completed " + s))
        .subscribe();

flux.connect();
```

This will give you something like the following, with all entries completed and no retries:

```
doing dangerous Entry 1
doing dangerous Entry 2
doing dangerous Entry 3
doing dangerous Entry 4
Throwing exception from Entry 4
doing dangerous Entry 4
Completed Entry 2
Completed Entry 1
Completed Entry 3
Completed Entry 4
```

Comment: Thanks! I considered that option, but I was hoping I would be able to use the error/retry handling on the root ```Flux``` to pause when something bad happened, sort out the mess, and then resume. Retrying on the inner ```flatMap``` calls will result in an awful lot of retries (and possibly race conditions) while the mess is being sorted.

Comment: After some reflection, I think this is the correct approach, and I've marked it as accepted. Errors on the main flux are not the appropriate place to be resolving errors from the flatmap.